# Transfer Files to Nexus 4 with Terminal

Tags: file-transfer, shell

I want to transfer files to my Nexus 4 using the Mac Terminal.

I tried to use the adb shell with adb push, but because I'm not root I'm not allowed to push to the sdcard.

Is there any way to mount the device as a regular drive or to use adb push without root access?

Comment: You should be able to use `adb push` even without root. What's the message you get when trying to `adb push ~/file /sdcard/file`?

Comment: As I wrote below it's "error: device not found"

Comment: What do you get if you try to run `adb devices` and `adb shell`?

Comment: Everything works fine. I see my device and I can log in to the shell. All normal commands like cd, ls, pwd etc work. Only push and pull throw this error

Comment: And just to confirm, trying to do `cd /sdcard/` works? (I know I'm being tedious, I just want to make sure nothing has been overlooked).

Comment: Yes. I also can view its content with ls

Answer (score 0):

You can't push to the sdcard's root, but you can push in any folder found in it, except `/sdcard/Android/data`.

Comment: I tried this but I got "error: device not found"

Comment: @user1839433: Have you enabled USB debugging?

Comment: Yes I enablded debugging, adb devices shows my device and I can see all data on my phone using adb shell and ls/cd/... I only can't push and pull

Comment: What do you mean when you say "You can't push to the sdcard's root"? Because you *can* push to `/sdcard/` no problem.

Comment: @dotVezz: Because I heard here and there that we can't. I can, but I'm on 4.1.2 and rooted, so I assume we can't and I tell a solution that I'm sure would work under normals circumstances. Anyway, It seems he has another problem...